# Looking for a message

Tags: cipher, knowledge, steganography

**I'm looking for a secret message found using these two clues:**

[image]

> 181-5 253-14 294-7 298-6 382-11
>  384-2 59-9 480-1 510-10 541-13

Comment: Made a mistake! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image:

> is transparent, but some letters have a white background. These letters spell out:  
> **Planet ebook dracula Pg wd**

This clues:

> a [book cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_cipher) with this book: https://www.planetebook.com/free-ebooks/dracula.pdf

The numbers:

> index into the book with `page#`-`word#` to get the words
>
> ```
> her excuses love leaden of well-being own risk later died
> ```
>
> Taking the initial letters of each word gives us the message, **HELLO WORLD**.

Comment: Correct! Nice work

Comment: @jwi Wait — *that* was the message? No way! When I first read this puzzle, I thought to myself, Rot13(unu, jung vs gur zrffntr jnf whfg "Uryyb Jbeyq"?).... and this is why I live life believing that there is a reason for everything...

Comment: haha I ran out of ideas when I was choosing a message! I was like why not?